# Emails with this attachment silently fail

Tags: email, attachments, mime-types

I recently had someone (@comcast.net) try to email me (@gmail.com and @something.edu) including in their email 3 text files and a .docx file. The email never reached me and they never received any bounce message. I eliminated attachments one at a time and determined that one of the text files was causing the problem. Inspecting the text file, it appears to contain a number of non-ascii characters. I stripped out all printing ascii characters and newlines with the following command:

```
dcollins@laptop:~/Downloads$ tr -d "\012\015\040-\176" < filename.txt | od -x
0000000 e9e9 e9e9 e9e9 9595 9595 9595 9595 9595
0000020 9595 9595 9696 9797 9797 aeae aeae aeae
0000040 97ae 9797 9999 9999 9997
0000052
```

As you can see, the attachment contains several instances of `0xe9`, `0x95`, `0x96`, `0x97` `0xae`, and `0x99`. Shouldn't my mail program decide that this attachment contains non-ascii characters, base-64 encode it, and send it using MIME? I noticed that the other text attachments were transmitted as `Content-Type: text/plain`, but since I didn't receive the problem attachment, I can't tell what my client did with it. Is this a bug in my client or in my ISP's mail server?

Comment: If *someone else* is trying to email you, then it is the *sender's* mail program, not yours, that has to MIME-encode the file.

Answer (score 0):

Download a free email client, then resend your attachment with that client. If it still fails, it's your ISP. If it gets sent, it's your mail client.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a mail client or two, and it's feasible that there is a bug.

However, there's no evidence here that the text file itself isn't corrupt.

Have your colleague copy and paste the text into a new document and send that to you, to see if the problem recurs. Have him save the file both as ASCII and Unicode, and see if that's causing the problem.